# Proving that for every prime number $p$ there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $-1 \equiv a^2+b^2\ (mod\ p)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I prove that for every prime number $p$ there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $-1 \equiv a^2+b^2\pmod p$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p=2$ then $-1=1$ so $-1=1^2+0^2$. Now when $p>2$, let $S$ be the set of squares of $\Bbb Z/p$. Then $|S|={p+1\over 2}$. Now consider the set $-1-S = \{-1-s: S\in S\}$. This has the same cardinality, and since

> $$|S|+|-1-S|>p$$

it must be that there is an element in their intersection, call it $c$ then $a^2=c$ for some $a$ since $c\in S$. But also there is $b$ so that $c= -1-b^2$ since $c\in -1-S$. So

> $$a^2=-1-b^2\iff a^2+b^2=-1.$$

Note:  there is nothing special about $-1$, in face **every** element works with this argument and so all things mod $p$ are the sum of two squares.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The case $p=2$ is trivial.  For odd $p$, use $\frac{p+1}{2}+\frac{p+1}{2}>p$.